# Assign role names to QAbstractItemModel now that setRolesNames() method is deprecated

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am attempting to follow the tutorial [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QML_and_QSqlTableModel) to display an SQLITE table in TableView with QtQuick2.  In that tutorial, the generateRoleNames() method calls setRoleNames() at the end.  However, that method has been deprecated.

There is a method doSetRoleNames(), but it is private, and unavailable to the derived QLSqlTableModel class.  Source code is [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/7be6438badf00f24b414c2d27d564e636e2b5eb5%3asrc/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.h#L239).

EDIT: The body of my roleNames() implementation:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> QLSqlTableModel::roleNames() {
  return roles;
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with role?

Comment: @piotruś It seems role is being used as a name identifier for the column.

Comment: Qt::role is used in data() function for example to differentiate tasks such as display

Comment: I saw that in the documentation for Qnamespace.  However, I also see role used as a column identifier both in the provided tutorial, which is in the official documentation, and in [this example](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/099df32ce03c8820ec29ef63fa825c7159887b08:examples/tableview/main.qml#L77) from the official examples (they use ListModel instead of TableModel).  I am a bit confused because role seems to be serving two different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [QAbstractItemModel::roleNames()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames)  is virtual, so to define your own role names, reimplement it in a subclass and return the desired hash. That means you must subclass QSqlTableModel.

(The main purpose of the role names are to receive roles from the model in QtQuick btw.)

Roles aren't "name identifiers for columns", roles and columns are orthogonal:

For each index, one can retrieve text, icon, color etc., or custom user-defined data.
One can have e.g. an arbitrary amount of custom roles with a single-column model.
However, an SQL table model is specific case where roles usually match the columns: As  QtQuick views are usually displaying a single column but can easily handle many roles, one defines roles corresponding to the data from the table columns, to easily access all the relevant data via roles.

Comment: Per the tutorial I am using (see link above), I am subclassing QSqlRelationTableModel into a class called QLSqlTableModel.  When I overwrite roleNames(), nothing happens; results remain the same.  When I set a breakpoint inside the body of roleNames(), I see that the method is never executed.

Comment: @onezeno: The signature is `roleNames() const`, it seems you forgot the `const`, judging from your pasted code above.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem.